# jQuery: loop a loop with different timeout values

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, settimeout

I am trying to loop through a couple of different values. The idea is that if a user clicks a button the loop should start to run, once it runs it should show a piece of code(in the example some basic text). I am trying to show a sort of dialog with different information, the duration depending on the time values(milliseconds), so the first starts with 3 seconds, right after that the second should be visible for 8 seconds, after this the last one should run for 2 second.

I had to make changes so that every loop the time is different. The example below has a kill switch, so that i can kill the loop. I hope that somebody can figure this out, I have tried a lot of hours and hours.

//plugin options

```
  step:[
      {
          time: 3000,
          name: 'mike',
          age: 30
      },
      {
          time: 8000,
          name: 'john',
          age: 37
      },
      {
          time: 2000,
          name: 'jessica',
          age: 25
      }
  ]
```

// the loop

```
  var timeouts = [];

$('.click').click(function(){
  $.each(options.step, function(i, value){

      var time = value.time;                                                        
      timeouts.push(setTimeout(function(){

          $('#target ul').append('<li>'+value.name+'-'+value.age+'</li>')

      },time));

  });

 });
```

// reset button

```
  $('.stop').click(function(){
      $.each(timeouts, function (_, id) {
          clearTimeout(id);
      });
      timeouts = [];
  });
```

**EDIT: the issue is that it needs a extra value(0) in the loop(first value should be a 0), as the the first setTimeout runs after 3 seconds, which means that the rest will use the value of there neighbor.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script sets 3 timeouts: show Mike in 3s, John in 8s and Jessica in 2s - so Jessica is first. If you want them to happen one at a time, you will need to accumulate these times:

```
var timeouts = [],
    accum = 0;
$.each(options.step, function(i, value){
    accum += value.time;                                                        
    timeouts.push(setTimeout(function(){
        $('#target ul').append('<li>'+value.name+'-'+value.age+'</li>')
    }, accum));
    // move the addition here if you want them to start immediately
});
```

([Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/WJrWF/1/), with immediate start)

The other way would be to start the next timeout once one just occurs, this would allow easier stop&go:

```
var cur = 0,
    $ul = $('#target ul'),
    tid;
function next() {
    if (cur >= options.step.length) return; // and call a final callback?
    var value = options.step[cur];
    $ul.append('<li>'+value.name+'-'+value.age+'</li>');
    cur++;
    tid = setTimeout(next, value.time);
}
function stop() {
    clearTimeout(tid);
}
```

([Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/WJrWF/))

Comment: thanks but this doesn't work, well it works but the timing isn't correct. It waits 3 seconds before it shows the first one(the example it is 3 seconds, my test its a little bit more)

Comment: That's in the comment - move the accumulation behind the timeout, then the first one will have a timeout of zero.

Comment: tried that, but it's not starting, it still uses the wrong time value

Comment: found the solution I think, there should be an extra value of 0 inserted at the beginning of the array(or how its called)

Comment: Hm, worksforme. See the demos I've linked (And no, you should not need a 0 value in the steps array)

Comment: But how about a reset, because i want to re use the function.

Comment: Just reset `cur = 0` right before (or even in) that `return` statement, where you also could have placed a finish-callback.

Comment: Yes i see it, i had a scope var at first, but it should be a global var(if these names are correct)

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through all the values and the setTimeout will call the function wrt to the time in the data. The 'stop' variable should  be a global variable which will act as your kill switch

```
var stop=0;

$('.stop').click(function(){
     stop=1;
  });
function responseFunction(value)
{
    if(!stop)
   alert(value.name+" "+value.age);
   else return;
}
 $.each(step, function(i, value){
    setTimeout(function(){
                        responseFunction(value);
                        },value.time);
  });
```

Comment: this will give me the same issue that i have, and the issue that i am having is that the timing isn't correct, it should start directly, but i doesn't as there is an tiemout. So i have to insert a extra time value in the loop, with the value 0 i think

Comment: so you are saying that the timeout value is not working.. right?

Answer (score 0):

I just want to provide an alternative way with less code.
You only need to use a plugin named [jquery-timing](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/). It makes timing things easier in jQuery.

```
$('#target ul').repeat().wait(function(i) {
   this.append('<li>'+options.step[i].name+'-'+options.step[i].age+'</li>');
   return options.step[i].time;
}).until(options.step.length);

function stop() {
   $('#target ul').unwait();
}
```

---

As I am a big friend of clean code, here exactly the same once again. But this time with named functions instead of anonymous ones:

```
$('#target ul').repeat(addCodeStep).wait(stepTimeout).until(options.step.length);

function addCodeStep(i) {
   this.append('<li>'+options.step[i].name+'-'+options.step[i].age+'</li>');
}

function stepTimeout(i) {
   return options.step[i].time;
}

function stop() {
   $('#target ul').unwait();
}
```